# Get the difference between arrays

Tags: php, arrays

my mind is going to explode. need to get the array element which has an id of 4 and 6 in array 1. basically its the difference of these two arrays. i tried using for each loop but i cant get the output that i want

```
Array 1(
 0 => array(
        id: 1
          )
 1 => array(
        id: 4
          )
 2 => array(
        id: 5
          )
 3 => array(
        id: 6
          )
 )

Array 2(

 0 => array(
        id: 1
          )
 1 => array(
        id: 5
          )
      )
```

the output i want:

```
new Array (
 0 => array (
      id: 4
            )
 1 => array (
      id: 6)
        )
```

what i've tried:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $value2) {
      if($value2['id']  !== $value['id']){
        $result['id'] = $value2['id'];
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Show us your foreach loop

Comment: Your first array seems invalid with multiple index of 0 and 1

Comment: typo error for the index

Comment: Please add your solution as answer, so it will be helpful for others

Comment: Put your solution in an answer post below, not in the question, please.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [array_udiff()](http://php.net/array_udiff) function like this.

```
function diffCompare($a, $b)
{
    return $a['id'] - $b['id'];
}

$difference = array_udiff($array1, $array2, 'diffCompare');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_diff_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) to get your expected output.

```
array_diff_key($array1, $array2)
```

> It compares the keys from array1 against the keys from array2 and
>   returns the difference. This function is like array_diff() except the
>   comparison is done on the keys instead of the values.

Comment: This will not work: `This function only checks one dimension of a n-dimensional array.`

Comment: Updated. Current one outputs as expected.

Comment: Nope. Close but no.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
   foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $value2) {
     if($value2['id']  !== $value['id']){
        unset($array1[$key2]);
      }
}
}
```

Explanation:
  array1 got more array element than array2, my problem here is i need to get the elements in array 1 that is not existing in array2. so to solve this, if array2 element is existing in array1, unset the element in array1 that is the same in array2. array1 will return the elements which is not existing in array2

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)